# What will be the time complexity of this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

What will be the time complexity of the following code/algorithm?
Shouldn't it be O(a^2)? My teacher said no and that I need to think harder and focus on the given constraints. Can anybody help me with this?

```
function(int a, int b)
{
    for(i=0; i<a; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<a-i; j++)
        {
            k = a-i-j;
            if(8*i+4*j+2*k == b)
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

Constraint:

- 2*a < b < 8*a
- b is always even

Comment: If b is even then the code returns early before doing all iterations. I think it's Theta(a*max(1, b-4a)) if b is even, Theta(a^2) if b is odd. It's not a realistic or practical problem.

Comment: Assuming that you copied the code correctly, and that you're supposed to assume that arithmetic operations take O(1) time (which you shouldn't assume when the input is just two numbers), then O(a^2) is correct because when b is an odd number, the `if` condition is never satisfied, regardless of the constraint.

Comment: @PaulHankin It is normally correct in this case to say the running time is O(a^2). The same argument can be made about linear search - it takes O(1) time if the target is at the start of the array, but we don't write O(index of target), we write O(n).

Comment: @kaya3 yes, O(a^2) is correct, but if you want a tight (Theta) complexity, you have to consider both arguments. For linear search, you say "O(n) comparisons in the worst case", or "O(n) comparisons in the average case" (assuming the element is equally likely to be distributed in the array). Here, there's no natural interpretation of "worst case" or "average case" given a particular a and b. Given the question, it's explicit that the answer that the person is looking for is not the slack O(a^2) bound.

Comment: I think that this is clearly not a practical or realistic problem, but rather a technical theoretical question about complexity. I can't understand the problem as anything but asking for a mathematically precise expression of the runtime based on both arguments.

Comment: @PaulHankin I think if the teacher *did* want a mathematically precise answer then they should have made the question mathematically precise, and the feedback on the student's attempt should include the observation that arithmetic with arbitrary integers cannot be done in O(1) time, and presumably the feedback should also include that a tight Theta bound is required. By my reckoning, either the question posted here is not exactly the question the teacher set, or the teacher is teaching misconceptions (possibly their own misconceptions).

Comment: @kaya3 you may be right about what the teacher should or should not have said or how they should have presented the problem. I would agree with you that most runtime complexity at the undergraduate level underspecifies exactly what is being measured by "runtime", but assuming O(1) arithmetic is standard (perhaps implicitly formalized using the transdichotomous model, but more likely just glossed over). It's an imperfect world, but whereas you're seeing this question as a mistake, I have provided an interpretation that's reasonable assuming only a modest amount of sloppiness.

Comment: @PaulHankin Assuming O(1) arithmetic is standard when the input is an array of integers, in which case it's typically assumed that the integers are bounded by O(log n) to fit into machine words of size log n. This doesn't work when the input is two integers; if simply reading the input takes O(1) time then the concept of "input size" is absent from the problem, and if the integers are assumed to be bounded then the algorithm would run in O(1) time because there would be only finitely many possible inputs.

Comment: Arguably, yes, I'm being more pedantic about it than you are. But on the other hand, the pedantry I'm applying is important for understanding the concept of time complexity at a deeper level; whereas in your interpretation the question is (as you point out) artificial, and not (IMO) teaching anything important for a student to learn.

Comment: I am really really sorry for having wasted your time by posting incomplete question. I had missed the condition that b can only be even. And about practicality, teacher wrote this code in one of his submissions in a coding challenge and he asked us to compute the time complexity of his code as an exercise for homework. And for time complexity o(a^2), i think the reason that is not the correct answer is because this code will never run for 'a^2' times no matter what test case you take, there will always be at least one solution before both loops reach to 'a' under the given constraints.

Comment: @PaulHankin corrected the question

Comment: @kaya3 corrected the question

Comment: Yes, if b is restricted to be even then it's a different matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code will stop early when it finds i, j such that 8i+4j+2(a-i-j)=b, that is 6i+2j=b-2a.

The j loop goes from 0 to a-i, so for j to be in range, have b-2a = 6i+2j < 6i+2(a-i) = 4i+2a, which gives 4i > b-4a.

So we'll need to execute (b-4a)/4 iterations of the i loop before we have a chance to find a j.

I'll skip the details, but it's possible to check for a>=6 there's always a j such that the loop exits when i is the first value that's at least (b-4a)/4 (given that b is even and 2a<b<8a).

Counting iterations (and counting the inner loop as always a iterations rather than a-i iterations, which will at worst give a factor of 2 error), we get a bound of a*max(1, b/4-a) iterations.

I've skimmed the details a lot here, but the result is that the complexity is Theta(a*max(1, b/4-a)).

Comment: So even with *b* even, it is still quadratic. Take *b* = 8 *a* − 2 for instance.

Comment: However, I observe that if *b* ≤ 4 *a* + O(1), then your multivariate complexity gives O(*a*), so perhaps the constraint was intended to be 2 *a* < *b* < 4 *a* ?

Answer (score 1):

With the constraints given, assuming that you are interested in the worst-case complexity, it is *still* O(a²). Perhaps there is another constraint missing?

Paul’s answer is good and gives a precise account of the complexity. However, to find a worst-case complexity, you can just exhibit the worst case.

The equation 8i+4j+2k = b rewrites as **3i+j = b/2−a**. Because j < a−i, the left-hand side is at most 3i+(a−i−1), in other words 2i+a−1. Because i < a, this is at most 2(a−1)+a−1, in other words 3a−3.

Take the largest possible b: b = 8a−2 (which satisfy both constraints: b is even and 2a < b < 8a). The right-hand side of the equation becomes (8a−2)/2−a, in other words 3a−1. This is strictly greater than 3a−3, therefore the equation has no solution. In this situation, the algorithm tries all (i,j), which is quadratic.

Comment: Yes, if you want to describe the runtime given only the first argument then O(a^2) is the best you can do. Is there a reason not to use the second argument too? I consider it like Dijkstra's algorithm with runtime O(n + m log n) which would be O(n^2 log n) if you take the "worst case" number of edges, but that's not usually done because then the runtime is a less useful bound.

Comment: I agree. The OP expressed a complexity using only *a*, did not say us what “typical” values of *b* would be, and seemed to imply that a worst-case complexity was desired, so I gave it a shot. Again I guess we are left trying to guess what is the actual use case for this algorithm…

Comment: @Maëlan i really had not thought about the b=8a-2 case. In that case, worst case time complexity is indeed O(a^2). I believe teacher too didn't consider this case, I think worst case time complexity is actually O(a^2). I'll talk to my teacher regarding this. Since it's not an actual standard question, i don't think there's an actual standard correct answer. However, i believe your answer is actually true if we consider the b=8a-2 case. Is there any other such case where this algorithm would have to run at least a^2 times?

Comment: Well the second-largest possible b (b = 8a−4) is the only other unreachable value (the right-hand side is 3a−2, still greater than 3a−3) so you’ll have the same number of steps (the number of loop iterations is O(a²) but it is not a², it is a+…+3+2+1 = a×(a+1)/2). But these worst cases are not the only case when you actually get the quadratic behavior. According to Paul’s precise bound, you get O(a²) whenever the growth of b is such that b/a = 4+Ω(1) (in other words if b grows at least proportionally to *a* with a factor strictly greater than 4; for instance, if b ≥ 5a).